# Jenkins & Git - Which is the most appropiate trigger to run tests?

Tags: git, testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, moodle

I'm developing plugins for a major system (Moodle), so Continuous Integration will be useful for me.

The idea is to checkout Moodle stable version branches I want to publish the plugin for, to run the test with these versions.

But as I've never worked with Jenkins nor Continuous Integration, I've no clear when would be the best moment to trigger the build that run the tests. These are the build triggers Jenkins offers:

- Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)
- Build after other projects are built
- Build periodically (cron-like; I don't think would be suitable)
- Build when a change is pushed to GitHub (could be)
- Poll SCM (can't see difference with the periodic build)

Apart from these, we have the Git hooks, which at first sight I find them more interesting that what is above.

- Pre/post commit
- Pre/post merge (could be nice for triggering builds only for certain branches)
- Pre/post push

**Note:** Git plugin for Jenkins fails always when fetching Moodle repo, it seems because its quite long size (I don't know if Git plugin es necessary/important for this approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my experience, the best is to trigger the "build" whenever a commit is pushed to the repository. I think that is what "continuous integration" is about.

Recently, Mark Nielsen developed a tool to help integrate the tests for Moodle plugins with the Travis CI tool (http://travis-ci.org/).

"The tool provides a template of the travis configuration file - perfectly documented - as well as excellent usage information." (https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=323384).

The tool allows you to run several tests like php and js lint, moodle's own code style checker and phpunit and behat tests. It also tests with several versions of PHP with mysql and postgresql databases. You may also test you plugin in different versions of Moodle, but the default branch is MOODLE_30_STABLE.

It is availabe on https://github.com/moodlerooms/moodle-plugin-ci

Answer (score 1):

**About Triggers:**
*It completely depends on your choice or on the scenario of the project. However i will give you my thoughts based on my experience with `Jenkins`.*

> Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)

It is bothering to always trigger the build manually

> Build after other projects are built

I never had to use it. Maybe it can be used in very specific scenario (ex: When a project depends on another one, or if the project is too big and you want to run it alone maybe)

> Build periodically (cron-like; I don't think would be suitable)

Will build periodically, event if there is no change on the code. If email trigger is enabled it will bother you with emails. Evend worst if there are other people included on the `mailing list`

> Build when a change is pushed to GitHub (could be)

It is useful if you are developing project alone and want to see the result immediately after you push changes. However this option sometimes doesnt work. So a workaround to this is to make `Poll SCM` check for changes every minute. (`*/1 * * * *`)

> Poll SCM (can't see difference with the periodic build)

The main difference is that Poll SCM wont build at the time you specified but instead it will firstly check for any changes. If there is no change at all, it wont build, whereas `Build periodically` will do. 
This is the option i mostly use. It is a very useful one. I usually schedule to check at nights with *email triggering enabled* and the first thing to do in the morning check emails for any build failure

**About Git hooks:**
If you want to trigger build for certain branches, *you have the option to choose which branch to build by default on jenkins*. I also havent had any scenario that i was forced to use Git hooks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most appropriate trigger for your developing scenario were the:

- Build when a change is pushed to GitHub

because it is the one, which lets you detect integration errors as quickly as possible (this is one of the main benefits of continuous integration practice).

To get out the best from this trigger policy you should integrate your code into the shared repository several times a day, or at least daily.

> The idea is to checkout Moodle stable version branches I want to publish the plugin for, to run the test with these versions.

For this scenario the trigger:

- Build periodically every night

is the most appropriate because integration test usually are longer then unit one.

So recapping:

- run **unit test when a change is pushed** to GitHub (to test your plugin)
- run **integration test every night** (to test interaction between your plugin and Moodle)

For the following:

> Apart from these, we have the Git hooks, which at first sight I find them more interesting that what is above.
>
> - Pre/post commit
> - Pre/post merge (could be nice for triggering builds only for certain branches)
> - Pre/post push

please ask another question better clarifying it.

For the following:

> Note: Git plugin for Jenkins fails always when fetching Moodle repo, it seems because its quite long size (I don't know if Git plugin es necessary/important for this approach).

please ask another question providing stack trace.